# How to randomly sample very large pyArrow dataset

Tags: python, pandas, large-data, pyarrow, huggingface-datasets

I have a very large arrow dataset (181GB, 30m rows) from the huggingface framework I've been using. I want to randomly sample with replacement 100 rows (20 times), but after looking around, I cannot find a clear way to do this. I've tried converting to a pd.Dataframe so that I can use df.sample(), but python crashes everytime (assuming due to large dataset). So, I'm looking for something built-in within pyarrow.

```
df = Dataset.from_file("embeddings_job/combined_embeddings_small/data-00000-of-00001.arrow")
df=df.to_table().to_pandas() #crashes at this line
random_sample = df.sample(n=100)
```

Some ideas: not sure if this is w/replacement

```
import numpy as np
random_indices = np.random.randint(0, len(df), size=100)
    
    # Take the samples from the dataset
sampled_table = df.select(random_indices)
```

Using huggingface shuffle

```
    sample_size = 100
    # Shuffle the dataset
    shuffled_dataset = df.shuffle()
    
    # Select the first 100 rows
    sampled_dataset = df.select(range(sample_size))
```

Is the only other way through terminal commands? Would this be correct:

```
for i in {1..30}; do shuf -n 1000 -r file > sampled_$i.txt; done
```

After getting each chunk, the plan is to run each chunk through a random forest algoritm. What is the best way to go about this?

Also, I would like to note that whatever solution should make sure the indices do not get reset when I get the output subset.

Answer (score 0):

Just create some random integers with [randint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) the select the respective rows with [select](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.17.0/en/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.Dataset.select):

```py
from datasets import load_dataset
from random import randint

bla = load_dataset('rotten_tomatoes', split='train')

random_rows = [randint(0, bla.num_rows-1) for _ in range(10)]

sample = bla.select(random_rows)

print(sample)
```

Output:

```
Dataset({
    features: ['text', 'label'],
    num_rows: 10
})
```